# Saving a glTexImage2D to the file system for inspection

Tags: c++, opengl-es, textures, opengl-es-2.0, framebuffer

I have a 3D graphics application that is exhibiting bad texturing behavior (specifically: a specific texture is showing up as black when it shouldn't be).  I have isolated the texture data in the following call:

```
glTexImage2D(GL_TEXTURE_2D, 0, GL_RGBA, width, height, 0, GL_RGBA, fmt->gl_type, data)
```

I've inspected all of the values in the call and have verified they aren't `NULL`. Is there a way to use all of this data to save to the (Linux) filesystem a bitmap/png/some viewable format so that I can inspect the texture to verify it isn't black/some sort of garbage? It case it matters I'm using OpenGL ES 2.0 (GLES2).

Comment: https://renderdoc.org/docs/behind_scenes/opengl_support.html ?

Comment: Black is the default error color, so will typically be returned for a texture which is either an unsupported format, or incomplete (e.g. wrap modes not set up).

Comment: @Rabbid76: Yes. Thank you for help. Just marked the answer as solved.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

If you want to read the pixels from a texture image in OpenGL ES, then you have to attach the texture to a framebuffer and read the color plane from the framebuffer by [`glReadPixels`](https://www.khronos.org/registry/OpenGL-Refpages/es3.0/html/glReadPixels.xhtml)

```cpp
GLuint textureObj = ...; // the texture object - glGenTextures  

GLuint fbo;
glGenFramebuffers(1, &fbo); 
glBindFramebuffer(GL_FRAMEBUFFER, fbo);
glFramebufferTexture2D(GL_FRAMEBUFFER, GL_COLOR_ATTACHMENT0, GL_TEXTURE_2D, textureObj, 0);

int data_size = mWidth * mHeight * 4;
GLubyte* pixels = new GLubyte[mWidth * mHeight * 4];
glReadPixels(0, 0, width, height, GL_RGBA, GL_UNSIGNED_BYTE, pixels);

glBindFramebuffer(GL_FRAMEBUFFER, 0);
glDeleteFramebuffers(1, &fbo);
```

All the used functions in this code snippet are supported by OpenGL ES 2.0.

Note, in desktop OpenGL there is [`glGetTexImage`](https://www.khronos.org/registry/OpenGL-Refpages/gl4/html/glGetTexImage.xhtml), which can be use read pixel data from a texture. This function doesn't exist in OpenGL ES.

To write an image to a file (in c++), I recommend to use a library like [STB library](https://stb.handmade.network/), which can be found at [GitHub - nothings/stb](https://github.com/nothings/stb).

To use the [STB library](https://stb.handmade.network/) library it is sufficient to include the header files (It is not necessary to link anything):

```cpp
#define STB_IMAGE_WRITE_IMPLEMENTATION
#include <stb_image_write.h>
```

Use `stbi_write_bmp` to write a [BMP file](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/BMP_file_format):

```cpp
stbi_write_bmp( "myfile.bmp", width, height, 4, pixels );
```

Note, it is also possible to write other file formats by `stbi_write_png`, `stbi_write_tga` or `stbi_write_jpg`.